# FRM-40403: A calling form has unapplied change. Save not allowed

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

Im working with oracle 10g , when i try to submit my form the following error

FRM-40403 says that A calling form has unapplied change. Save not allowed

I search on internet about that error mesagge but i could not find a clear answer,
Could someone tell me what is this error and how can be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form A (where you made some changes) and then called form B.
If you want to commit the changes in form B you get the error above.

You need to do a `post` instead of a `commit` in form B.

Then the changes will be validate and available but not yet saved.
If you commit in form A afterwards all the changes will be saved.